# How to convert logit shap values to probability

Tags: python, catboost, shap

I've been trying to convert shap values with the logit link to probabilities for all my features in a dataset. The model_output ='probability' parameter doesn't work for my catboost model. I want to convert the shap values for each feature so that when you sum them they equal the probability shown on the force plot.  I've used a prewritten function to convert log odds to probabilities but the sum doesn't equal the same in the force plot. Any suggestions?

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(catboost)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(df_X_test)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], df_X_test.iloc[0,:],link='logit')
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I have been using for instance-level explanations:

```py
shap_values = (shap_values / sum(shap_values)) * probability
```

Where `shap_values` is a list, `len(shap_values) = n_features`, one Shapley value per feature and the `probability` is a double in [0, 1].

This will scale your Shapley values from whatever domain they are in, to the predicted probability.

Comment: What is probability in this instance? where do I get the number from?

Comment: Probability would be the output of your ML model. If **X** is your instance, and **f** is your model, then `probability = f(x)`